# Is it possible to add external data to CloudKit?

Tags: ios, icloud, cloudkit

I'm writing an iOS app that uses data collected from websites.  A large amount of data is retrieved when parsing the content so it needs to come from a backend server where data can be collected and added to the database once rather than parsed on the device.

I've looked at BaaS frameworks like Parse and am considering using this, but I'd like to know if it is possible to add records to CloudKit externally from say a Linux server?  I've looked everywhere and can't find anything other than adding records programmatically (from the app) or via the dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create an OSX app (no other platforms are supported yet) that is communicating to the same CloudKit container. But then that app also needs to be signed and submitted to the app store. You don't have to make it public, you just need to submit it.

Comment: Thanks, that could work too.  For my situation I have to update data frequently (multiple times daily) so I want to either run this on a cheap/low-power linux machine that will always be on, or push it to AWS.  I decided to go with Parse.com which has a REST API that is easy to push data to.  The other consideration is trying to write all of the HTML parsers in objective C would be a headache compared to Python.  Thanks again for the response.